# Error 997 - I/O operation pending while writing to file with FTP

Tags: c, winapi

```
LPDWORD dwWritten = 0;

        BOOL bSuccess = InternetWriteFile(hFTPFile, lpTempBuf, strlen(lpTempBuf), &dwWritten);
        if (bSuccess == FALSE) {
            DWORD err = GetLastError();
            printf("InternetWriteFile - Error = %u\n", err);
            InternetCloseHandle(hFTP);
            InternetCloseHandle(hINet);
            printf("bob5");
            continue;
        }
```

This snippet of code is causing me problems - I have checked the buffer and its contents and length are fine. All previous steps (InternetConnect, InternetOpen, FTPOpenFile) are returning their correct values.

However, I am having a problem with this function, which causes an infinite loop, always returning error 997 - which entails that my I/O operation is constantly in progress and never finishes.

Inside my file, in a seemingly random pattern, I am getting sometimes the total content of my buffer, sometimes only a single letter, however, the error loop always remains a constant, regardless of file content.

Furthermore, my goal is actually to append to the file, so should I FTPCommand before the InternetWriteFile function?

Comment: Are you using `INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC` for async transfers? If so, you need to set a callback using `InternetSetStatusCallback` that will get called when an async transfer is complete.

Comment: Yes I used that flag. Is it necessary? It was the flag that most appeared aplicable to my situation, because all the others entailed no networking.

Comment: You can use it by all means but then you have to handle async transfers properly.

Comment: I decided to do the same thing through FTPCommand, and it is working fine. Thanks for the answer though, you should post as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: On a side note, this code will not compile as shown, as the last parameter of `InternetWriteFile()` expects a `DWORD*` but you are passing it a `DWORD**` instead. `dwWritten` needs to be declared as `DWORD` instead of `LPDWORD`.